# grunt Cannot find module 'coffee-script'

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mean-stack

I used the following commands to install a mean stack and create an app:

```
> sudo npm install -g meanio@latest // Get the mean cmdline
> mean init myApp // create your first app
> cd myApp && npm install // Install dependencies
> grunt // Launch mean
```

but when I get to the final grunt command I get the error:

`module.js:333
     throw err;
           ^ Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:331:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:357:17)
     at require (module.js:373:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/eddie/ResFour/node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt.js:16:1)`

I've tried various solutions on stackoverflow to no avail:

[NodeJS - setting up mean.io cannot find module errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694273/nodejs-setting-up-mean-io-cannot-find-module-errors)

[Cannot find module 'coffee-script'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011290/cannot-find-module-coffee-script)

I also cleared npm cache and reinstalled a few times.

Comment: what happens when you run `which coffee`? what version of coffee are you running?

Comment: In package.json, what it said about coffee-script's version?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

1. Remove `node_modules` directory.
2. `npm cache clean` to empty downloaded temporary dependencies, just in case.
3. `npm install` again, and better not to interrupt it while running.

These solved most of these problems for me.

Comment: You might have to run `sudo npm install` as the command could throw admin exceptions after a couple of minutes.

Comment: @TimvanderLippe `chmod +R $(whoami) ./npm`

Comment: worked, but the "npm cache clean" part is obsolete. skip it.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
npm install --save-dev coffee-script
node -v # v0.10.31
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and in the end of the log I was receiving such a message:

```
...
http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/-/all
Killed
```

The problem was the lack of enough memory in my VM. One solution was to use swap is mentioned [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/3867).