# module.js:338 throw err in node.js

Tags: node.js

I'm using ubuntu and I'm trying to run a script using nodejs and i'm getting this error.

```
/home/bebz/Documents/test# node server.js
module.js:338
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/bebz/node_modules/express/lib/express.js:6:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

What is the problem? I'm in the right directory and also i tried to run it using root but nothing happens.

Inside server.js is

```
// get dependencies
var app = require("express")();

// handle request and response
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send({name:"Hello Wolrd"});
});

// initializing a port
app.listen( 5000);
```

A simple example just to show that node.js is working.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It seems like the script has an unmet dependency - meaning you have to install the module "merge-descriptors" first.

It also seems like the script is using "express" (and "merge-descriptors" actually looks like a dependency of "express") - because this didn't throw an error some dependencies seem to be installed already.

So you could try to install the missing ones via `npm install` or `npm update`.

Update: According to [npmjs.org](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) "merge-descriptors" is an dependency of "express". Looking at your stacktrace shows that you have "express" installed globally - so you should try `npm update -g`

If that doesn't solve your problem you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694273/nodejs-setting-up-mean-io-cannot-find-module-errors).

Comment: I used `npm update` and it is working now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Node will also throw 338's when the target script doesn't exist. Basically a file not found notice.

Comment: @UberDoyle: Actually an unmet dependency is, from a technical point of view, a simple "target script doesn't exist"

Comment: @FlorianLoch I have the same issue, I tried npm update, but it is not working.

Comment: @FlorianLoch - There is no npm_modules folder on installed express.

Answer (score 2):

npm update

I see this when the module install order is not perfect, or multiple modules exist.

npm update sorts this out deprecating the incorrect versions.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you get `module.js:338 throw err;` try to check whether `npm` is installed in your machine or not.

```
UserName$ npm -v
```

If you get the version name, then it's clear that `npm` is installed.

If you don't get the version name, there is some problem with your installation or it is not installed.

To install `npm`, type this command in your Terminal:

```
UserName$ curl -0 -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh
```

Also notice I added `sudo` before the `sudo sh` command depending on your users permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when module name and file name does not match. It's resolved after using the same name for module and file name. e.g.

```
module - Hello,
File name - Hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

you should install merge-descriptors module. Open your terminal or command prompt and run this command:

```
npm install --save merge-descriptors
```

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue , u should try npm install , npm update is also an option but with npm update latest npm version will be installed in your local environement . This is not desirable for global project as u may find unmet dependencies issue at global environment then.

I would suggest use npm install