# can't install module 'merge-descriptors'

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I'm new to node.js.
I'm using WebStorm. I work on Windows.

I configured my app to run on node.js and when I try to run it I get this error:"Cannot find module 'merge-descriptors'".

I followed these post trying to solve it: [How do I resolve "Cannot find module" error using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/nodejs-how-to-resolve-cannot-find-module-error),
[module.js:338 throw err in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377583/module-js338-throw-err-in-node-js)

I ran "del /s /q node_modules" (parallel to "rm -rf node_modules").
Now I'm trying to run "npm install -g" and I'm getting this error:

See screen shot below
[image]

I've tried to understand it and to look for information about it in the net to no avail.

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide your files folder in workspace  only names

Comment: The error occurs in the file express.js in line 16: var mixin = require('merge-descriptors');

Comment: @alon do not run `npm install -g`. If you are trying to install a project from a package.json file you should only be running `npm install` in the root where the package file is.

Comment: Thanks @travis it solved the problem! Please write it again as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When installing the dependencies for a package you should be using `npm install` and not using the `-g` flag.

The `g` flag, or `global` is used when installing a package globally, which places them in a direct location that is not accessible by the project.

See https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Answer (score 7):

I had similar issue installing the module, I tried npm install or npm update but my network would timeout. However what I did is very simple:

```
npm install merge-descriptors --save
```

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you're seeing is that the logged in user doesn't have permission to write to the install directory. This can be overcome with `sudo` command, ex., `sudo npm install`. But as others have indicated, if you have to do this then something about your app's configuration could be wrong.